# Include World concept of cucumber in site-prism

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

How to include World concept of cucumber in site-prism?  So that I can include test_site class in World and then no need to instantiate test_site class every time in step functions.  Is it possible?

I'm using Ruby with Capybara and site-prism; not rails!!!

My test_site class is:

```
class TestSite
  def home
    TestHomePage.new
  end
end
```

Can't I do like this?

```
module Some
  class TestSite
    def home
      TestHomePage.new
    end
  end
end

World(Some)
```

Comment: There are a couple of extra `end`s in the code above...

Comment: Sorry...but that is not actual problem...updated now...

Answer (score 1):

The SitePrism readme has a suggestion on how to deal with this, see here:

- http://rdoc.info/gems/site_prism/file/README.md#Epilogue

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question.

As Nat suggested, I followed SitePrism readme here:

[[http://rdoc.info/gems/site_prism/file/README.md#Epilogue][1]](http://rdoc.info/gems/site_prism/file/README.md#Epilogue%5d%5b1%5d)

I changed App class to Module and used World(App) in support file, so that whenever I need to use an element in step definition, I can just give 
    `page_name.element_name.click`
instead of     `@app.page_name.element_name.click`

I changed the below class into Module and included the Module in World as World(App)

`class App
  def home
    Home.new
  end
end`

Modified as

`Module App
  def home
    Home.new
  end
end`

Is there anything wrong if I do change the class into Module??
For me everything seems fine, want to have a confirmation, before I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module to return all pages that you want.
In the support folder create a `object_factory.rb` in this file you can add:

```
Module Pages
   def my_page
     MyPage.new 
   end
end
```

in the file `env.rb` you can insert:

```
require_relative 'object_factory'
```

and

```
World(Pages)
```

The objects created in the module Pages will be available to your all step definitions